# Clone a object only with few properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, clone

Is there a way to clone an object with only few properties of the object in JS?
For example..

```
var Person = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 32,
    salary: 20000
};
```

I have to create another person object with just the name and age property so that it will look something like this :

```
var clonedPerson = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 32
};
```

I could do a deep clone of the object and *delete*. But I wanted to know if there are better ways to do it.

Comment: You could just go through the properties of the old object and only copy across the ones you want.

Comment: If you don't want to use delete, you have to define a new object with only the properties you want. There is no native method for copying an object with only desired properties.

Comment: `var clonedPerson = { name: Person.name }`

Comment: @adeneo only works for strings, if you do this with a property which has an object inside, it will reference, not clone

Comment: @user2415266 - I see only prrimitives in the OP's example

Comment: @adeneo you shouldn't assume it is only primitives...and he is talking about deep clone, which implies to me that this was just an example, not the actual data.

Comment: @user2415266 - unfortunately I have neither the time nor the space to write an entire iterative function that does deep clones based on keynames, in the comment field, but feel free to answer the question.

Comment: @adeneo you shouldnt be writing *any* answer in the comments - fully featured or otherwise!

Comment: @Jamiec - pointing the OP in the right direction with a comment, when one can't be bothered to write a fully fledged answer explaining the issue, is just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the latest ES6, you can achieve this by the following code..

```js
const Person = {
  name: "Bob",
  age: 32,
  salary: 20000
};
const { salary , ...clonedPerson } = Person

console.log(clonedPerson)
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution. Unfortunately I am not using ES6.

Answer (score 2):

More simple?

```js
var Person = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 32,
    salary: 20000
};
var ClonedPerson = jQuery.extend({}, Person);
delete ClonedPerson.salary;

console.log(JSON.stringify(Person));
console.log(JSON.stringify(ClonedPerson));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP said, **"I could do a deep clone of the object and delete. But I wanted to know if there are better ways to do it."** Still, you're using `delete` ?

Comment: I have thought very simple that way, just wanted to confirm. And ironically, you exposed a better way ... :)

Comment: @MarcosSedrez Thank you.. But yeah.. as Pranesh has mentioned.. I wanted to know if there is any alternative way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative approach using Array member methods:

```
var clone = Object.keys(Person) // convert to an Array of Person keys
            .filter(function(key){return ["salary"].indexOf(key) == -1;}) // exclude key salary
            .reduce(function(clone, current){clone[current] = Person[current]; return clone;}, {}); // convert back the array to a cloned literal object
```